# "Command not found" error when running program

Tags: csh, centos-6

I'm trying to run a program, and keep encountering a `"Command not found"` error.

I've checked that the appropriate directory is in `$PATH`, and that the file itself has execute permissions. I've tried running it in the directory using `./programname`, but with no luck.

I'm running CentOS 6 with csh.

Comment: What program are you talking about?

Comment: Console output would be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelK- The program is a pre-built executable, it's not a standard linux utility or anything

Comment: @gman- The only output I receive is "programname: Command not found"

Comment: What happens when you try to run it with `/full/path/to/programname`? What does your PATH look like?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz- When I try to run it with the absolute path, I receive "full/path/to/program/programname: Command not found."
My $PATH contains the full/path/to/program/ as it's first entry.

Comment: dcrooney - looks as through you may be missing the leading slash? /full/path/to/program

Comment: Please post `ls -l /full/path/to/program/programname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check "**file ./programname**" and "**ldd ./programname**" outputs. This is most probably compiled for some other platform or architecture than you run.

Comment: This is exactly what happened. I was inadvertently given a 32-bit binary; this led to a bit of an issue when trying to execute it on a 64-bit machine :)
I wish the error was more descriptive than "Command not found", though...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
% ls -l /bin/date
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 58960 Jun 26  2008 /bin/date

% !!:2
/bin/date
Tue Nov 15 18:04:50 EST 2011
```

But replace `/bin/date` with your `/full/path/to/programname`

The `!!:2` is a C shell history substitution `!!` means previous command. `:2` means third word (they are numbered from 0)